# Swift3 passing value into array that is property of class

Tags: arrays, swift3

I have a swift viewcontroller - BulkGridCell, in it I have a property set up for an array:

```
var arrGroup: Array = [AnyObject]()
```

I am instantiating BulkGridCell in another viewcontroller, BulkProcessController:

```
for (index, value) in self.arrData.enumerated() {

//add each data cell
let gridCell = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bulkGridCell") as! BulkGridCell
  resizeGridCell(vGridCell: gridCell.view, frameY: frameY, frameH:50.0)
  gridCell.bIsHeader = false
  gridCell.bIsDeleteProcess = bIsDelete
  gridCell.buildCell()
  self.svData.addSubview(gridCell.view)

  //pass the data entity to data cell
  gridCell.arrGroup.addObject(value)
```

when I try to add value to the array arrGroup I get this error message:

*Value of [AnyObject] has no member addObject*

I'm crossing over from Obj-C to Swift so this has me a bit confused, isn't addObject a method of the Array object, I'm not trying to run that method off of value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: value is a Core Data entity if that helps. I was reading that I might have to cast these to AnyObject, though when I tried value as AnyObject I still got the same error.

Comment: Do you mean `append`?

Comment: Tried append and got the same error. Wait, just tried it again and it worked. Must of had a syntax issue first time I did it. Throw this in as an answer and I'll give you the bump! : )

Answer (score 0):

So I'm noticing a couple issues that could be fixed with the correct syntax.

First if you have a custom object, **and you want to create an array** of those objects, the type of that array should **[be in square brackets like this]**. 
Lets say I have an object called **Friend** that I want to add into an array. I would create the array like this.

```
var arrayOfFriends: [Friend] = []
```

This creates an array of Friends objects and it's currently empty.

To add elements into an array, you want to use the .append instance method on your array.

```
let friend1 = Friend()
let friend2 = Friend()

arrayOfFriends.append(friend1)
arrayOfFriends.append(friend2)
```